# AndEngine: ConfigChooserOptions cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, andengine

My goal is to use RenderSurfaceView and attach png images as textures to that view. PNG images have alpha regions, so i want to make RenderSurfaceView transparent in order to see VideoView behind. 
I have found answers with information about AugmentedReality extension which makes RenderSurfaceView transparent, but i'm unable to build given example https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/examples/AugmentedRealityExample.java because org.andengine.engine.options.ConfigChooserOption does not exist in AndEngine source.

1. Question: Is it possible to make RenderSurfaceView transparent by using Augmented reality example code?
2. Why ConfigChooserOption does not exist any more? And what to use instead of that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: About your Q2: Did you use GLES2-AC branch of AndEngine? Because ConfigChooserOption does exist in GLES2-AC branch. (https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine/blob/GLES2-AnchorCenter/src/org/andengine/engine/options/ConfigChooserOptions.java)

Comment: Thank you! That solved my problem. And also managed to solve question1. Just to mantion, if you want to use that example, it is mandatory to use permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />. I always forget that :)